# Passing an Array as Arguments in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to prepare a sql statement with unknown amount of parameters! These parameters are past on in an array. The normal syntax for the function would be:

```
$stmt->bind_param("string of types",param1,param2,...,paramN)
```

The problem is I dont know how to add parameters in the function  $stmt->bind_param out of an array

I have this code but it does not work:

```
$stmt= $conn->prepare($request['query']);
if(isset($request['params'])){
call_user_func_array('$stmt->bind_param',$request['params']);
}
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

$request['params'] contains the right parameters that need to be added in the function.

But the call_user_func_array gives me this error:

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '$stmt->bind_param' not found or invalid function.

I think call_user_func_array might not be the right function to use!
I googled for hours but could not find a solution for this small problem.

Comment: Please read [the documentation](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) on the functions you are using. Note the examples show you how to properly call object methods via this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'),$request['params']);
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem is it gives a value and not a reference:  Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given

Comment: Solved it! I used   `call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'),refValues($request['params']));` with this function i got on the internet:`function refValues($arr){
    if (strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.3') >= 0) //Reference is required for PHP 5.3+
    {
        $refs = array();
        foreach($arr as $key => $value)
            $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
        return $refs;
    }
    return $arr;
}`

Answer (score 4):

If you're using PHP 5.6+, you could also use the [`splat`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) operator rather than using `call_user_func_array`, e.g.

```
$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$request['params']);
```

This would be neater for your use-case, since there's an initial argument to `bind_param` that would otherwise need to be `shift`-ed onto the front of the array of arguments.

Comment: I'm not using 5.6+! Because it's just a test on a usbwebserver and thats 5.2 but your solution would be the best if I had that version

Answer (score 2):

To use a method as a callback parameter to `call_user_func_array`, use an array with the object name and the method name in it as the callback parameter.

Check PHP's `call_user_func_array` documentation page for further explanations: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.call-user-func-array.php

```
// Call the $foo->bar() method with 2 arguments
$foo = new foo;
call_user_func_array(array($foo, "bar"), array("three", "four"));
```